# Firebase cloud functions -@google-cloud/storage initialization

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

First question here.

I am trying to write a firebase cloud function to compress a file. I went through a lot of examples on the web but my code keeps getting stuck at two points.

```
1.const {gcs} =require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

When I use this construct in require , I get the following error

TypeError: require(...) is not a function

If I change this to 
`const {gcs} =require('@google-cloud/storage');` the error goes away but apparently the object isn't initialized because I get this error when I try to access it like so

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bucket' of undefined
>       at exports.onfilechangecompressor.functions.storage.object.onFinalize.object
>   (/user_code/index.js:21:27)
>       at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

This is the line where I use gcs like so

`const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);` where bucket is the object.bucket returned ( object is returned by onFinalize ).

Can someone please tell me how to initialize the storage so it works and returns a valid object.

My node.js version is 8.12.0
firebase version is 5.1.1

Comment: Is your bucket name correct?

Comment: What version of `@google-cloud/storage` are you using?  The APIs changed in 2.0.0.

Comment: @AlchemistShahed - I am using the default bucket so there is no bucket name.

Comment: @DougStevenson- The version of @google-cloud/storage is 2.1.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation for 2.x](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/#using-the-client-library) shows this:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

You're adding `()` after the require, which you're discovered is not correct.

You then go on to initialize it like this:

```
// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
});
```

You may not need to specify the project id if you're running in Cloud Functions or other Google environments.

After that, you can get a reference to your default bucket:

```
storage.bucket()
```

You can also use the Admin SDK to invoke the same cloud storage APIs:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const storage = admin.storage();
storage.bucket();
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the admin approach and it worked. Thanks a ton !

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @doug-stevenson this approach works great for a single environment. Is there a way to perform the same without explicitly specifying projectId / bucket name since it ties the code to a specific Firebase environment?